# Connecting to the Internet from a Proxy via another Proxy

Tags: java, proxy, http-proxy

I'm building a simple proxy server. It doesn't connect to the internet directly but via other proxy servers choosing the most appropriate one dynamically using some algorithm. And that proxy server connects to the Internet. That's a requirement. 
So it looks like this:

```
Client ---> My Main Proxy ---> Proxy1 ----> Internet
```

or

```
Client ---> My Main Proxy ---> Proxy2 ----> Internet
```

or

```
Client ---> My Main Proxy ---> Proxy3 ----> Internet
```

I know how to build a proxy which is `My Main Proxy`. But how can I connect `My Main Proxy` to `ProxyX`? 
Or rather how can I connect `My Main Proxy` to the Internet via  `ProxyX` (and return the result to `Client`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the type of proxy (Socket or HTTP) but both the `Socket` and `URL` classes have methods to set a proxy server (to set them to create the connection through a proxy).

For example:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.host", 8080));
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
```

And for a TCP socket connection

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.host", 80));
Socket socket = new Socket(proxy);
InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(address, port);
socket.connect(socketAddress, 1000);
```

Comment: what's `new InetSocketAddress(address, port);` on the 3rd line of the 2nd example? if we're connecting to a proxy, why would we need one more pair of address and port?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp That is the destination address and port, you need to tell the proxy to what address to forward your connection to.

Comment: please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533150/unable-to-make-a-request-via-proxy

Comment: But I'm telling it by sending the headers to the proxy, am I not?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp the `Socket` class has multiple constructor, in this example I'm using one that accepts a `Proxy` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.net.Proxy)