# Unable to make a request via proxy

Tags: java, proxy

I want to make a request via a proxy. This, with no proxy, works fine:

```
Socket sock = new Socket("example.com", 80);
OutputStream oStream = sock.getOutputStream();

//Writing headers to send to the proxy

String request = rType + " " + uri + " HTTP/1.0";
oStream.write(request.getBytes());
oStream.write(endOfLine.getBytes());

String cmd = "host: "+ header.get("host");
oStream.write(cmd.getBytes());
oStream.write(endOfLine.getBytes());
System.out.println(cmd);

//............................
```

But this, with a proxy, isn't working well, it hangs:

```
Proxy prx = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("my proxy ip address", 1234)); // predefined ip and port
sock = new Socket(prx);
sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("example.com", 80)); //hangs here
oStream = sock.getOutputStream();

//............................
```

What's up with that?

Comment: Are you sure about Proxy.Type.SOCKS and not Proxy.Type.HTTP ?

Comment: @MrSimpleMind, sorry, the error I had when I used "HTTP" was **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Proxy**

Comment: @MrSimpleMind, the proxy itself exists and working properly.

Comment: did you try bind? will it run when using proxy for your jvm with system properties, like when you run java with flags as `-Dhttp.proxyHost=your-proxy-ip` `-Dhttp.proxyPort=the-port` .. just to make sure it really works

Answer (score 0):

As @MrSimpleMind already stated: Use `Proxy.Type.HTTP` instead of `Proxy.Type.SOCKS`.